# when should I exchange Google tokens (time)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I know that , refresh token never expires, and I can use it to exchange it for an access token as needed. I wrote app engine application and I have refresh token saved in database.  everything is great.

I know that,  for example, In order to have access to Google drive, I need access token (I can get it from refresh token, no problem) **but:**

**QUESTION:**
should I exchange tokens code on each request of Google drive? for example I need to upload file and then remove this. should I exchange access code twice? |

Question 2)
should I update  Drive with new creditial, on each request? or how should I do that?

```
Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
```

Comment: I don't know the Java libraries at all, but in Python this is taken care of for you: it attempts to access with the current access token, and if that has expired it does a refresh call.

Comment: I have another question. I want to know when should I get access token. on each request? or when... or I just want to update Drive , from Database Creditial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Question 1, I prefer to watch the expiration time of the access token. If it has < 5 minutes && > 1 minute left, I use it, and then after completing the Drive transaction, I request a new one ready for next time. If it has < 1 minute left (or has expired) I fetch a new one before performing the Drive operation. It's more code, but this provides the quickest response time to the end user.

On Question 2, do you mean each request to Drive, or each request to your app? There is no need to create a new Drive object for each Drive request.